# How do you find a file in the media library using the file URL?

Tags: media-library, wp-filesystem

We have about 2000 files in our media library and we are working on an audit to organize the files and create a name hierarchy.

But until that is done, I am trying to locate a handful of specific files to replace. I don't know what the files are named in Wordpress, I only have the URL to download the file.

Is there a way to search for the file in the dashboard using the URL?

Comment: If you have the url to download, then you have the file name. Your url should be something like http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/filename-150x150.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, you would need to run a query on directly on the database using WPDB. So you would do something like this:

Add this in your `functions.php` file:

```php
// retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL
function get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $the_attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
    return $the_attachment[0]; 
}
```

And then you can apply it wherever you like this way:

```php
$attachment_url = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/28/just_for_the_lolz.jpg';
$attachment_id = get_image_id($image_url);
```

`$attachment_id` will have the attachment ID so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This does help quite a bit.